# Find (bigger) nearest value for join table

Tags: postgresql, join

i have two tables in my PostgreSQL.

- ADDRESS (street, city, zip)
- ZIP (zip, gps_lat, gps_long)

ZIP is CHAR(5) in both, but every ZIP is in format: 'XXXXX' 5 numbers. Example: '55555' or '12345'.

I want select all ADDRESS with joined ZIP.
Problem is, some address have zip, which isn't in ZIP table. For this situations i want join NEAREST (BIGGER) zip value.

I created DB function for it (psc == zip):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION lekari.get_psc(pscx character)
RETURNS character
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
begin
    if exists (select 1 from spravni_celky.zip where psc = pscx) then
        return pscx;
    end if;

    while not exists (select 1 from spravni_celky.zip where psc = pscx) loop  
        pscx =  cast(cast(pscx as integer) + 1 as char(5));
    end loop;

return pscx;
end;$function$;
```

And then create simply select:

```
select * from lekari.address lad
join spravni_celky.zip p on p.psc = lekari.get_psc(lad.psc)
```

It works, but for 12 rows in ADDRESS (and about 200 in ZIP), the query time is almost **4 min**!

Plan B is stored two ZIP in DB, one current and one for joining.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to use the GPS coordinates to calculate the "nearest"? Instead the the "ZIP code"?

Comment: It's used for search nearest address by GPS coords. But for that i have to know, where address is. I have only GPS coords for ZIPs.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to obtain a USPS published list of all valid zip codes with lat/long. Any address with a code not in the list is an invalid code which needs correcting.  Also have you looked at zip-code map lately. What makes you think the "next higher" zip is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=cd98e33c41c8b1eff58f4fe7aad4a202)

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (a.city, a.street, a.zip)
    *
FROM
    address a
JOIN
    zip z
ON a.zip <= z.zip
ORDER BY a.city, a.street, a.zip, z.zip
```

Join against all ZIPs that equals or are greater. Then give out the first records for each joined address.

If zip exists: The first fitting ZIP equals. So the first ordered records is the own zip.

If zip does not exist: The first fitting ZIP is the next bigger one.

`DISTINCT ON` gives out the first records of an ordered group.

Answer (score 0):

You've already had an answer to the question you asked, and several comments about the strategy overall. I just want to jump on this later point as, in a previous life, I wrote a ZIP Code distance-calculator product. It was great, back *before the Internet*, but I wouldn't recommend it now. Here's why:

- There are affordable APIs for doing distance and proximity calculations with curb-side accuracy. So much better than crude centroid calculations. I look into this from time-to-time, but don't know what the best solution is these days.
- If you get an update to your lat-long coordinates, the math for distance-on-a-sphere is really basic. There are examples everywhere. Not super high fidelity, but fast. Kind of nice for a blocking query where you want to filter down to a rough area before doing a more sensitive search. Postgres has a point type, but maybe you're already using that. (PostGIS has support for R-trees, I believe, which is a pretty awesome index structure for real polygons.)
- If you *must* use ZIP Code centroids, you must update the data regularly. There is no reliable method to interpolate the coordinates for the missing ZIP Codes, you have to go and get coordinates that someone calculate ("made up", see next point.) Here's what the USPS seems to offer:
  https://www.unitedstateszipcodes.org/zip-code-database/
- "Centroid?" As people have noted, a ZIP Code is a *route*, not a *polygon*. So the polygon gets faked. And then a central point is artificially selected. It might be in the middle of a lake, it's not a high-fidelity point data set.
- Centroid data with simple trig works okay(ish) over very long distances, and not so great in dense areas. So, the denser your population, the worse the outcome. Well, coast-to-coast also gets things a bit messed up becuase the world is not a sphere.
- ZIP Code numeric sequence is *not* a measure of proximity. Several words: Hawaii, Guam, Northern Marianas, Palau, Alaska.
- It sounds like you've got leading zeros covered, like 01776. Good on you. Developers in some locations (*Hello California, I'm looking at you!*) forget about places like, say Massachusetts where the first digit of the ZIP Code is 0.
- You're obviously dealing with US data, which often leads to the question "what about Canada?" Nope. Canada has something like one post code for every 10 people by royal decree, or something. For that, you would *really* be better off using a curb-level address service.